# Results for heat equation with interior point condition

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am looking for any results concerning the study (and for example potential existence and uniqueness results) of the heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions and with an additional interior point condition, i.e:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},x\in[0,1],t\geq 0$$
with $u(0,t)=u(z,t)=u(1,t)=0$, $z\in(0,1)$, and $u(x,0)=f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. I was wondering if the classical existence and uniqueness results were extendable to this case, and whether this could be done in an obvious way? Any comments or references to literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with breaking the problem into $0 \le x \le z$ and $z \le x \le 1$?

Comment: @TrialAndError, I was asking this to myself, do you believe the two problems are equivalent?

Comment: @TrialAndError more precisely, if there is existence and uniqueness on $[0,z]$ and also on $[z,1]$, can we deduce that there is also existence and uniqueness on $[0,1]$ with the additional interior condition?

Comment: If you have a solution, then it's going to have to solve the equation on both pieces individually. So I think this is all you can do.